# UICollectionView can not change imageView size of cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview, uicollectionview

I want to configure the prototype-cell and imageView to a new width and height, but that does not work for the imageView.

**How can I change the size of the imageView to fit to the cell size?**

I have a newly created `CollectionView` from scratch. On IB I added a `ImageView` to the prototype-cell with the tag 100.

The cell size is changed in the code via `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` which works fine. Afterwards I configure the frame of the imageView to fit the cell frame. The log shows that this works, but on the simulator the imageView size does not change!

#### IB and the result in the simulator

[image]

#### Log

```
[collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 78] SETTING SIZE For Cell 0, width: 104.000000
[collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 78] SETTING SIZE For Cell 1, width: 104.000000
[collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 78] SETTING SIZE For Cell 2, width: 104.000000
[collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 78] SETTING SIZE For Cell 3, width: 104.000000
[collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 78] SETTING SIZE For Cell 4, width: 104.000000
[collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 78] SETTING SIZE For Cell 5, width: 104.000000
[collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 78] SETTING SIZE For Cell 6, width: 104.000000
[collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 78] SETTING SIZE For Cell 7, width: 104.000000
[collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 78] SETTING SIZE For Cell 8, width: 104.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 52] Entering Cell: 0
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 60]      width: 50.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 61]      height: 50.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 64]      new width: 104.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 67]      imageView width: 104.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 68]      cell width: 104.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 52] Entering Cell: 1
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 60]      width: 50.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 61]      height: 50.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 64]      new width: 104.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 67]      imageView width: 104.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 68]      cell width: 104.000000
[... and so on ...]
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 52] Entering Cell: 8
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 60]      width: 50.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 61]      height: 50.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 64]      new width: 104.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 67]      imageView width: 104.000000
[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 68]      cell width: 104.000000
```

#### CollectionViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController

@end
```

#### CollectionViewController.m

```c
#import "CollectionViewController.h"

@interface CollectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Collection view
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 9;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    DLog(@"Entering Cell: %ld", (long)indexPath.item);

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    CGRect frame = [imageView frame];
    DLog(@"\t\twidth: %f", frame.size.width);
    DLog(@"\t\theight: %f", frame.size.height);

    frame.size.width = 104;
    DLog(@"\t\tnew width: %f", frame.size.width);

    [imageView setFrame:frame];
    DLog(@"\t\timageView width: %f", imageView.frame.size.width);
    DLog(@"\t\tcell width: %f", cell.frame.size.width);

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.jpg"];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGSize mElementSize = CGSizeMake(104, 104);
    DLog(@"SETTING SIZE For Cell %d, width: %f", indexPath.row, mElementSize.width);
    return mElementSize;
}

@end
```

Comment: You're using autolayout. You can't modify the .frame or .bounds properties if you have it enabled.

Comment: **That did the trick**. Perfect and Thank you! I [changed the autolayout in IB](http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/smat-disable-autolayout.png) for the cell

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone. I faced a similar issue. I was able to resolve it. If you create a custom UICollectionViewCell in the `- (void)awakeFromNib` function 
call `autoresizingMask` on the UIImageView for cell

```
_imageViewForCell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

This should resize your image in your collection view cell.